# Is there some way to see if my graph has a normal distribution from a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, distribution

So I did an histogram in python and the frequencies where very irregular but it still looks like a normal distribution. So to confirm this I want to know if 95% of the data is in range of [μ - 2σ, μ +2σ]. But I´ve been searching something that helps but can´t find anything. I tried somethings but didn´t work.

```
data_athle = df[df['Sport']=='Athletics']
height= data_athle['Height'].dropna()

plt.hist(height, bins=50)

plt.grid()

plt.xlabel('Participant height in cm')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Height of athletisism participants')
plt.show()
```

Here is the code hope someone can help me figure out how to do it

Comment: It takes more than having 95% of the data be within +/-2sigma of the mean to be normal.  A common diagnostic tool is generate a [quantile-quantile (qq) plot](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/qqplot-quantile-quantile-plot-in-python/).

Answer (score 2):

That's a bit more of a data science, statistics, question rather than directly programming.

First, if you think there's a normal distribution there but the histogram looks ugly, try different numbers of bins. Especially if you don't have that many data points, having the bins too small makes it hard to see the underlying distribution.

Anyway, one way you can think about this whole idea is: A normal distribution is uniquely defined by its mean and standard deviation, so just compute mu and sigma for your data and plot a normal distribution with those parameters on top of your histogram to see how it looks.

As for "checking if ... is in the range of ..." well, that's a simple filtering operation.

You can use the pandas functionality to grab all the heights that are larger than mu - 2sigma and smaller than mu + 2sigma, and then count how many of them there are.

```py
heights_in_2sigma = height[height < mu - 2 * sigma & height > mu + 2 * sigma]

percentage = len(heights_in_2sigma) / len(heights)
```

At least *something* like this; haven't checked if I got the syntax exactly right. But that's the idea!